# What is the valid numerical range for Content-Range?

Tags: http

Specifically, is this range legal?

```
Content-Range: 0-1/12818084
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*bytes-unit*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.12) is missing. Here are the production rules for [*Content-Range*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16):

> ```
>    Content-Range = "Content-Range" ":" content-range-spec
>
>    content-range-spec      = byte-content-range-spec
>    byte-content-range-spec = bytes-unit SP
>                              byte-range-resp-spec "/"
>                              ( instance-length | "*" )
>
>    byte-range-resp-spec = (first-byte-pos "-" last-byte-pos)
>                                   | "*"
>    instance-length           = 1*DIGIT
> ```

But with `bytes` as *byte-unit* it would be valid:

```
bytes 0-1/12818084
```

- `0` is *first-byte-pos*
- `1` is *last-byte-pos*
- `12818084` is *instance-length*

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
Content-Range: bytes 0-1/12818084
```

According to [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), this is legal. There is no minimum limit as long as in `Content-Range: bytes a-b/c`, *a <= b*, and *c > b*.

Practical example: I was able to obtain a 2 byte partial response from mirrors.kernel.org (I checked that I could also get a 1 byte response):

[image: A 2 byte partial response, much like the one in the question]